# Creating a side plate in Solid Works

Tags: solidworks

I am a complete solidworks novice trying to create the part pictured in the orthographic schematic below but i am really struggling. I hoped someone might be able to guide me in creating this part.

[image: Sideplate schematic]

I began by creating a sketch as follows but i get stuck after this. I'm not sure how to align the top two circles in the center of the plate or how to create the rounded edge on the bottom of the plate.

[image: progress]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend the first couple of solidworks tutorials. Creating something when you don't understand what you're doing generally leads to underdefined,  incorrect parts.

But search for centreline (a construction line) or right click on a normal line to give you some geometry to align the top two circles with. A filet is what you want for the rounded edges. Also the green boxes are constraints,  and I can see you have some you don't want, like the left and right uprights have been forced to be vertical. To add constraints, right click on the parts you want to constrain and select what you need. To delete them, click on the green squares and press delete

Also your sketch is currently floating in space, not fixed to the geometry like it should be. To fix this, select the origin and a circle (hold shift) and select make concentric. Basically you need to do a tutorial.

When a line is fully defined, it will turn black. When the whole sketch is fully defined, you can move on, go to the features toolbar, and select extruded boss/Base. If you move on without fully defining the sketch, you can accidently drag lines out of place without knowing. Which is the worst to try to hunt down and fix.

Comment: Also to add, its a good idea to try avoid cramming all in one operation. Sure you can make it one extrude but its cleaner if the holes are separate features.

Comment: Yes agreed. Especially if you want to use things like hole wizard to deal with tolerances. Although I prefer to have all my dimensions in a skeleton sketch to be able to check dimensions and avoid breaking references when you change an extrude below etc, but that's personal preference / having had to learn in ProE

Comment: Its a bit of double edged sword. Sure it decouples things up in history. But now your geometric references are more tightly bound to your skeleton. But yeah that makes sense in many cases.